# Jquery set different input text and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

right now I'm using `$.val()` to set an input's value. But I want the user to see a different text in the input, and still send the value set with `val()` to the server. I tried using `$.text()` but it doesn't work. Is there a way to set the html `value` attribute and also set a distinct text inside the input for th## Heading ##e user to see?

I'm not posting any code because its pretty generic. The reason I need this is because I want to display a nice date string in the text (I'm using a datetime picker) and send a compacted version of the string to the server.

**EDIT**

Ok, hope this helps:

```
<input class="form-control date" id="booking_time" name="hour" type="text">
```

In Javascript I have something like:

```
var date_booked = new Date()
$("#booking_time").val(date_booked.toDateString());
```

But I want the input's value that is sent to the server to be the date **whithout** the `toDateString` proccessing, and still show the `date.toDateString()` in the text box. To do that, I hoped this would work:

```
$("#booking_time").val(date_booked);
$("#booking_time").text(date_booked.toDateString());
```

But it doesn't.

Comment: datepickers have formatters and they store date objects so not clear what problem is. You can parse date object and send any way you want to server and use the format option to display the way you want. Please provide full details

Comment: _"using $.val() to set an input's value. But I want the user to see a different text in the input, and still send the value set with val() to the server."_ Tried setting `.val()` to set text to display , send formatted value to server ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't explain myself correctly. I'll add an edit.

Comment: i suggest you make an data attribute and there store the data you want to save in database and during submit in the server side language you submit the data attribute to be saved in database.

Answer (score 2):

You can try storing the date you want to send to the server in a variable and then hook into the click event of the form's submit button to change the value right before submitting like so:

```
var date_booked = new Date()
$("#booking_time").val(date_booked.toDateString());

$("#id-of-submit-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#booking_time").val(date_booked);
});
```

The only problem is that if the user edits the input then it will overwrite their edit and send the variable instead. To get around this you can use another variable to detect a change in the input:

```
var submitvardate = true;
var date_booked = new Date()
$("#booking_time").val(date_booked.toDateString());

$("#id-of-submit-button").on("click", function() {
    if (submitvardate) {
        $("#booking_time").val(date_booked);
    }
});    

$("#booking_time").on("change", function() {
    submitvardate = false;
});
```

Comment: Your answer is a creative workaround, thanks. Anyway, I'll wait a couple of days just to see if I can find other ideas.

Comment: Sure, I would suggest looking into the html5 "date" input field. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can try sending your value by ajax

```
var date_booked = new Date()
$("#booking_time").val(date_booked.toDateString());
$("#form").on("submit",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : '',
        type : '',
        data : {
            hour : date_booked 
        },
        success : function(data){
            // do something ...
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```